# ¿Por qué AJAX se ejecuta hasta el 2do click y no en el 1ro?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo una función en js que utiliza AJAX para subir un archivo, si no he seleccionado ningún archivo y hago el click al botón subir la acción del js se ejecuta sin problemas (muestra un alert si no se ha seleccionado un archivo), pero si selecciono un archivo y hago click al boton subir (ahí es donde se ejecuta el AJAX), no funciona con el primer click, sino que debo hacer un segundo click y es entonces cuando se ejecuta sin problemas. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
function vacio() {
      
      var x;
      x = document.getElementById("archivo").value;
     
      if (x != "") {

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".upload").on('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            
            var formData = new FormData();
            var files = $('#archivo')[0].files[0];

            formData.append('file',files);

            $.ajax({
                url: "subir.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function(response) {
                if (response == "0") {
                    Swal.fire({
                    position: 'top-end',
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Información guardada',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500}).then(function(){location.reload();});
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                    position: 'top-end',
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error al subir el archivo',
                    html: response
                  });
                  return false
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });});
    } 

    else {
    Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Debe seleccionar un archivo',
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 1500
            });
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="archivo">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary upload" value="Subir" onclick="return vacio();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por que tienes un  `$(document).ready(function()`  dentro de tu funcion  `vacio` la cual lo llamas con evento onclick. `$(document).ready` se ejecuta cuando el DOM termina de cargarse. lo puedes solucionar quitando lo de tu funcion.

Ejemplo:

```
function vacio() {  
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("archivo").value;

    if (x != "") {          
          var formData = new FormData();
          var files = $('#archivo')[0].files[0];

          formData.append('file',files);

          $.ajax({
              url: "subir.php",
              type: "post",
              dataType: "html",
              data: formData,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,

              success: function(response) {
              if (response == "0") {
                  Swal.fire({
                  position: 'top-end',
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Información guardada',
                  showConfirmButton: false,
                  timer: 1500}).then(function(){location.reload();});
              } else {
                  Swal.fire({
                  position: 'top-end',
                  icon: 'error',
                  title: 'Error al subir el archivo',
                  html: response
                });
                return false
              }
          }
      });
      return false;

  } 

  else {
    Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Debe seleccionar un archivo',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          });
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente.